# Is it safe to call execl on a anonymous elf file?

Tags: linux

First create an anonymous memory block by

```
int fd = memfd_create("", MFD_CLOEXEC);
```

Note that I pass MFD_CLOEXEC flag.
Then I copy elf file content into this anonymous memory.
The elf is executed like this:

```
char cmd[128];
sprintf(cmd, "/proc/self/fd/%i", fd);
execl(cmd, "dummy", NULL);
```

MFD_CLOEXEC means that fd will be closed after execl, but here execl need to load elf content from fd. I do a simple test and it seems OK. But I am not sure it is safe or not.

update:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern uint8_t foo_data[]      asm("_binary_htop_start");
extern uint8_t foo_data_size[] asm("_binary_htop_size");
extern uint8_t foo_data_end[]  asm("_binary_htop_end");
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int exefd = memfd_create("", MFD_CLOEXEC);
    printf("%p %d %ld\n", foo_data, exefd, write(exefd, foo_data, foo_data_end-foo_data));
    char * const vv[] = {"htopp", NULL};
    //execveat(exefd, NULL, vv, NULL, AT_EMPTY_PATH);
    exefd = syscall(__NR_execveat, exefd, NULL, vv, NULL, AT_EMPTY_PATH);
    perror("");
    return 0;
}
```

I try with execveat but fail. syscall set errno to "Bad address", don't know the reason. elf content is generated by objcopy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine with real binaries (like ELF files), whether statically or dynamically linked.

`MFD_CLOEXEC` will not work with executable scripts (eg. files starting with `#! /bin/sh`). You'll have to omit that flag and leave the fd open in that case.

Instead of your `sprintf` / `execl` trick, you should look into using `execveat(fd, "", argv, env, AT_EMPTY_PATH)` (which unfortunately has the same problem with executable scripts opened with `O_CLOEXEC`, but doesn't rely on a `/proc` fs being mounted).

And of course, you should always use `(void*)0` instead of `NULL` with variadic functions like `execl()` ;-)

Comment: execveat is better for my case. Great answer!

Comment: But I fail to run the new process ^-^

Comment: Why are you passing it NULL instead of an empty string as in my example? Also, you shouldn't pass it a NULL environment variable, but the actual environment (you can declare it as  `extern char **environ` if `unistd.h` doesn't define it).

Comment: Oh, my fault. I am not really notice your idea. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use gdb to crack such process?  I tred with normal attach and gdb says "No executable file now."

Comment: It works fine with `gdb`; if its pid is 7989, `gdb -p 7989 /proc/7989/exe`. What were you thinking? ;-)

Comment: No. It is an anonymous deleted file. exe -> '/memfd: (deleted)'. I want to know if this is safe enough to forbid a cracker

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's deleted. You can "undelete" it with `cp /proc/7989/exe ./biggy`.